# "This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way."

Tags: c++, qt

My Qt program (g++ 4.4.0) is giving me the Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library error "This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way" when I close it. But when I run it in the debugger, I don't get the error message. Does anybody know a way to get some information about the crash? The message box just has an OK button.

**Edited to add:** Following Wimmel's advice, I attached to the debugger. There are two threads left alive, with ThreadID 1 and 3. The stacks look like this:

```
Level Function              File                           Line Address
0     VTagOutput            C:\Windows\syswow64\user32.dll 0    0x7529438d  
1     VTagOutput            C:\Windows\syswow64\user32.dll 0    0x7529438d  
2     USER32!EmptyClipboard C:\Windows\syswow64\user32.dll 0    0x752a2674  
3     ??                                                   0

Level Function                                    File                          Line Address
0     ntdll!LdrFindResource_U                     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll 0   0x76f5000d  
1     ntdll!LdrSetAppCompatDllRedirectionCallback C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll 0   0x76fdfabe  
2     ??                                                                        0    0x7b9609b5 
3     ??                                                                        0
```

Perhaps the second thread is displaying the error message? The first is a little strange: the top two rows are identical. I have nothing in my code that has `TagOutput` in its name, and neither does Qt as far as I can tell.

Comment: Maybe you can attach the debugger before clicking OK, and watch the stack frame of all threads to see where the error comes from.

Comment: All the symbols you're seeing are from system DLLs. Have you included debug information in your build?

Comment: @Alan: Yes. I suspect the program has already gone, and this is just the system's error-reporting mechanism.

Answer (score 3):

The only time I have ever seen that error message with Qt was when I first tried setting up a Qt development environment and had installed a number of different versions of MinGW. It seemed as though my executable was finding and loading a version of `mingwm10.dll` that didn't agree with everything else. I hunted down and eliminated all the versions of that dll except the one that I wanted and the problem disappeared.

Comment: I have hunted them down, and there are six(!) of them, in three different versions. How did you decide which one you wanted?

Comment: That would depend but try this. If you are using the Qt SDK, you probably want the one that is included with the SDK. One method that occurs to me is to copy each of the dlls you found into the same directory as the executable and try each of them, one at a time until you identify one that is compatible. If indeed, this is the cause.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But there's only one mingwm10.dll in my path, and it came with Qt, so I don't think this can be the problem. Meanwhile the program has stopped crashing, after some seemingly unrelated changes were made. So it's lurking in there...

Answer (score 0):

Use [procmon.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-Us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) and filter for process name and file access to find missing Dependencies.

I had the same Problem with Qt 5.0.1.
The program was missing some dlls from the Qt framework.
I found them in the Directory:

```
&lt;QTINSTALLDIR&gt;\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\plugins
```