# Error message when executing a Qt application

Tags: c++, qt

My program works correctly on my computer (Windows 7 64 bits), but seems to crash on another computer (Windows Vista 32 bits), with the following error dialog:

[image: WbMYW.png]

Qt informations:

[image]
[image]

I use the default Qt compiler.

Comment: what .dlls do you have in your .exe directory?

Comment: Did you tryed in debug version?

Comment: ...And were those DLLs also compiled in 32bit mode?

Comment: I didn't try in debug version. I got a bunch of dll in my directory. 12 exactly. For example icudt49.dll, libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll, libwinpthread-1.dll, and so on. Do you need all of them? How do I know if they were compiled in 32 or 64 bits ? I used the one on my computer, so maby they were in 64 bits? Idk...

Comment: I suppose this should be the 32 vs 64 bit problem.

Comment: Maby, but I compiled the application in 32 bits, I'm sure about that. But for the dll I don't know. How can I?

Comment: if you have installed Qt via the installer, it sure is the 32bit version (there is no 64bit installer on windows platform, yet)

Comment: Okay, well then it's 32 bits for sure, I used the default installer.

Comment: OK, I edited your question, now you need to add some details - version of Qt, what compiler you use, etc. Also, see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14948887/qt-5-0-1-application-will-not-execute-outside-of-qt-creator. Another thing - try creating a Hello World application, and if it fails on the other computer as well, then the problem is not in your code.

Comment: I did add the informations. :) I tried running a Hello World, it doesn't work on the 32 bits computer, but it runs on the 64 bits one. I tried in debug mode, same result: works on 64 bits, but not on 32 bits computer.

Comment: Then your problems seems to be answered by this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/15189938/492336. It looks like Qt 5 and MinGW are not compatible in some way. Just use the older Qt 4 instead.

Comment: That's indeed probably the problem's cause, but I need to stick with Qt 5.0. Do I have any alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see all the DLLs referenced by your EXE using [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). Also, the 32bit machine might not have installed the MSVC runtime required by some of the modules.

Comment: I think that the problem is not with missing DLLs - the error dialog would have been different. This error dialog is called when Qt aborts the program.

Comment: Exactly. All the dll are there. As I said, the application works fine on my computer, so it should too on my father's computer. But for any ready it is aborted before I can see anything.

Comment: You can also have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14948887/qt-5-0-1-application-will-not-execute-outside-of-qt-creator) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442567/this-application-has-requested-the-runtime-to-terminate-it-in-an-unusual-way).

Comment: Okay, I use Qt 5.0.1, maby that's the problem.